# Update password of firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I want to add functionality of changing password of firebase in angular ts. In my component i am calling function of changing password from submit button.

```
passwordChange(form: NgForm) {
const npassword = form.value.npassword;
const rpassword = form.value.rpassword;

if(npassword == rpassword){
this.authService.passwordChangeUser(npassword);

}
else{
alert("Password didnt match!");
}

}
```

from this component im calling my authService function passwordChangeUser with a parameter of npassword(new password). Here is my authService.ts

```
  passwordChangeUser(npassword : string ){
  var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

   user.updatePassword(npassword).then(function() {
     this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
     alert("successfully added!");
   console.log("successfully added!");
    }).catch(function(error) {
   console.log("unsuccessfull");
  alert("unsuccessful");
  });
 }
```

But this always show me unsuccessfull. It does not update password. I dont know what is the problem . Please help me how can i update my password. Any help will be appreciated Thankyou.

Comment: If you log the `error` value that is passed into your `catch`, what does it say?

Comment: [According to the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#set_a_users_password): _Important: To set a user's password, the user must have signed in recently. [See Re-authenticate a user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user)._